# Android. Обновление одного и того же фрагмента, после клика на выдвигающейся панели навигации

Tags: android, android-fragment, обновление

Всем привет!
Есть выдвижная навигационная панель + ТАБ из 3х вкладок. На каждой вкладке загружается свой фрагмент, при переключениях между табами все загружается корректно, но при нажатии на вкладке бокового меню необходимо перегрузить текущий фрагмент и обновить содержимое фрагмента новыми данными получаемыми из БД, данные из БД получаю корректно, но никак не получается перезаписать фрагмент.
Пробовал `replace`, `detach`, `attach` - не помогло.

Пробовал так:

```
FragmentMainPic fragmentMainPic = (FragmentMainPic) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_main);
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(fragmentMainPic);
ft.attach(fragmentMainPic);
ft.commit();
```

Здесь почему-то `fragmentMainPic`  возвращает `null`

и вот так, здесь `ft` загружается, срабатывает `newInstance`, но данные не обновляются

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
FragmentMainPic fragmentMainPic = FragmentMainPic.newInstance(1);
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_main,new FragmentMainPic ());
ft.commit();
```

Есть подозрение, что как-то надо обновляться через интерфейс

Comment: Вам же вроде во втором примере надо во втором параметре функции replace добавлять не новый объект класса, а тот, который создали до этой функции, то есть вместо new FragmentMainPic () написать fragmentMainPic. Разве не так?

Comment: Нет, так не тоже не обновляет. Есть какой-то рабочий пример, где происходит обновление одного и того же фрагмента на viewpager при нажатии на navigation drawer?